# How find equilibrant?

Tags: physics

[image: The problem]

If $F_1$ has magnitude 30 N and $F_2$ has magnitude 40 N, what is the exact magnitude and direction of the resultant vector?

I have 10 $10 \sqrt37$ and 53 degrees.

The next question is What is the equilibrant force that would be needed to compensate for the resultant force of the vectors F1 and F2?

What does that even mean? What am I supposed to do?

Comment: this may be more at home at physics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

If the vector sum of the two forces is $\vec{F}$, then the equilibrant is $-\vec{F}$.  The equilibrant has the same magnitude but points in the opposite direction.  (Adding a force and its equilibrant results in the zero vector.)